# C++ - List the NumberOfStudents taking SeveralClasses

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I was just wondering if anyone can help me with an issue. Fairly new to programming with C++ my teacher has given me the quick question relating to a number of students taking several courses.

I cannot however fathom how I am suppose to list the exact number of students who take multiple courses. I understand how to list the number of students, and the number of courses. But putting them both together is causing me some bother.

My attempt is listed below, I know I should not be using the || symbol so can anyone guide me to what should be in its place.

```
QString students = 
    QString::number(studentsList.noOfStudents() || coursesList.noOfCourses());
```

Comment: I then output with the following line
ui->MultipleStudentCourse->insert(multipleStudentCourse);

Comment: You also need info which student takes which class..